# Visual Studio Code: Using Mono and enabling IntelliSense

Tags: c#, mono, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a system-agnostic project using Visual Studio Code. This project will run on x86/64 Linux as well as Arm32 Linux and Windows. This project needs to depend on Mono.

I have VSCode installed on all the systems. I have debugging working (via mcs). Everything seems to be OK... EXCEPT IntelliSense. I need to have this feature working (I am on a team, and the team said the lack there-of would be a deal breaker)

Now, after research I found that DNX is what I'd have to install to get IntelliSense enabled for Mono projects. Except, DNX is obsolete. All the tutorials (for [example](https://peleshenko.net/2016/02/16/hello-world-in-visual-studio-code-on-linux/)) point to scripts that return 404. The DNX git site says "Just use .net core".. I can't use .net core for this project. I have to use Mono.

So, finally, my question is: How do I get IntelliSense to work in VSCode when my project is using Mono as it's runtime?

Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the same environment and could fix this problem with the following procedure:

First of all install some C# extension (I'm using the Microsoft one, at: 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp)

Create a new project within Visual Studio 2013 or other version (not VS Code). This procedure will create, among others, the file *YourProject.csproj* and *YoutProject.sln*.

After that, I used the folder of this projetc, and within VS Code choose the option *Open Folder*.
VS Code automatically searches for a *.sln* file, like described here (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp) and transcribed below:

> The available options include:
>
> - Selecting a project.json file will open a .NET Core project and VS Code will load that project plus the referenced projects.
> - Selecting a *.sln file opens a MSBuild-project. It will load the referenced *.csproj projects and sibling or descendant project.json files but no other project files that are referenced from the solution file.
> - **Selecting a folder will make VS Code scan for *.sln, project.json and *.csx files (C# scripts) and VS Code will attempt to load them all.**

From this point on my intellisense started to work fine. But it is not the end. For all new *.cs* files that you add to the project, is necessary to add them to the *YourProject.csproj*, in order to make the intellisense work for this new file too. Look for the TAG *ItemGroup* in this file and add your new file, like the example below:

```
<ItemGroup>  
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />  
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />  
    <Compile Include="YourNewFile.cs" />  
</ItemGroup>
```

Don't forget to recreate the *tasks.json* and *launch.json* files in order to compile and debug your project. (for Debug I understand you are already using, I installed the *Mono Debug* at: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.mono-debug)
PS. Maybe you don't have Visual Studio at hand, but you can try to create these files by hand. Unfortunatly I did not try this method...
Good luck!